# Is there a way to count iterations using a while loop?

Tags: java

Is there a way in which the program can count the number of iterations in which it took for the variable "`counter`" to reach its limit? I'm writing a basic program that demonstrates the use of a while loop and have been asked to display the number of iterations which have been printed out.

P.S. Sorry if there are any errors in the indentation/formatting of the code, I'm new to Java/programming. Thanks in advance.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int counter=2; counter<=40; counter+=2) {
            System.out.println(counter);
        }
        System.out.println("For loop complete.");

        int counter = 1;
        while (counter <= 500) {
            System.out.println(counter);
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your question has the answer isnt it? it will take 500 iterations to reach the limit.. as you are incrementing it by 1 every time

Comment: Usually, the answer to a question like this would be "add a counter variable and increment it in each iteration", but, well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just added a counter variable to track the loop execution count.

```
package main;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int counter=2; counter<=40; counter+=2) {
       System.out.println(counter);
    }
    System.out.println("For loop complete.");

    int counter = 1;
    int loopExecCounter = 0;
    while (counter <= 500) {
        loopExecCounter = loopExecCounter + 1;
        System.out.println(counter);
    counter++;
    }
System.out.print(loopExecCounter);
 }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I would recommend reading the Java naming conventions. `loopexeccounter` should be `loopExecCounter`.

Comment: I must admit... if this is a concise example of the exact problem you're trying to solve, then two values that are incremented at roughly the same time with exactly the same value is just wasteful?

Comment: @christopher I agree. The code is intentionally wasteful. Just wanted to answer what was asked instead of making it more confusing. Your answer explains the concept.

Answer (score 3):

If I've understood your question correctly, you're looking for something to keep incrementing the value *as part of the loop* rather than as a separate statement. Well, you could make it more terse using the `++` operator.

```
int x = 0;

while(x++ < 100) {
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

**Some Detail**

`x++` is shorthand for `x = x + 1`. There is a slight caveat with this. `x++` means return the value of x, then order it. So...

```
while(x++ < 100)
```

Will print out 0,1,2,3,4,5....99 (therefore iterating exactly 100 times) However, if you have `++x` instead, this says to increment *then* return. So:

```
while(++x < 100)
```

would print out 1,2,3,4,5...99 (and iterate 99 times).

Comment: Sorry, my question probably wasn't clear enough, bu what you've shared will also be helpful to me in the future so thanks!